# Kendo Grid - problems with search in database

Tags: search, grid, kendo-ui

My controller like this:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Error_Search([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, object[] ParaSearch)
    {
        object[] obj = new object[5];
        obj[0] = Convert.ToInt32(ParaSearch[0]);
        obj[1] = ParaSearch[1].ToString();
        obj[2] = Convert.ToDateTime(ParaSearch[2]).AddDays(-10);
        obj[3] = Convert.ToDateTime(ParaSearch[3]);
        obj[4] = ParaSearch[4];
        List<Vsoft.Lists.Model.SYS.SYS_Error> lst = new List<Vsoft.Lists.Model.SYS.SYS_Error>();
        ResultMessage result = new Vsoft.Lists.DALEntity.SYS.DAL_Error().SelectToList(ref lst, obj);
        return Json(lst.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

It will return Json(lst) correct.. but I can't bind it to datasource and refresh Grid after Ajax Call like this :

```
var requestData = { ParaSearch: arrObject };
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Content("~/Error/Error_Search")',
            data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
            type: 'POST',
            traditional: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            error: function (xhr) {
                result = false;
                alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
            },
            success: function (lst) {
                 var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
                 grid.dataSource.data(lst);
                 grid.refresh();
            },
            async: true,
            processData: false,
            cache: false
        });
```

Can AnyOne help me to solve this ? 
Thanks All !

Answer (score 0):

If ajax return is good enough, then using [setDatasource](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#methods-setDataSource) api call should be your friend.

```
success: function (lst) {
                 var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
                 var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                          data: lst });
                 grid.setDataSource(dataSource);                 
            }
```

**EDIT**: using [read](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-read) (read is just wrapper over `$.ajax`)
Hope you have configured your grid like:

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(20)
            .Read(read => read.Action("Error_Search", "Error", new { ParaSearch = []}))
         )
```

Then, wire up some event from where `ParaSearch` is originating and use [read](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-read) call as:

```
<script>
    function someEvent(e) {
        var requestData = { ParaSearch: arrObject };
        grid.dataSource.read(requestData);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply ! but it isn't still reload Grid with that lst(json). I added  grid.dataSource.read(); is it true ?

Comment: `read` simply calls the action you have set during grid initialization with ajax binding. Ya, you can do it this way, pass search parameter to data field of read.

Comment: If neither of approach work for you, please show your returned json and grid configurations.